# State-of-the-Art techniques on dynamic shortest path computations

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, shortest-path, dynamic-algorithms

Suppose that I would like to find the shortest path between two vertices in a dynamic graph, where the cost function of an edge changes occasionally. I understand that an efficient algorithm to target this problem must have efficient ways to handle the "cost updates" and the shortest path queries.

Does anyone know what is the state-of-the-art method proposed for this problem? And how is the performance like? If you could provide me with a reference as a starting point for my research on this topic, it would be greatly appreciated.

- The weights of the graph do not change while a shortest path computation is carrying on. It is safely to assume that the cost updates of edges happen periodically, like every 15 minutes.

Comment: Since [many distances can change](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1062/98), I don't think you can do better than just re-running your SSSPP algorithm of choice in the worst case. Also, just to be clear: are the weights changing while the algorithm runs, or do you want to maintain distances over time while weights change?

Comment: Also, [related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/retrieving-the-shortest-path-of-a-dynamic-graph?rq=1). And [another one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55824/dynamic-shortest-path-with-linear-programming?rq=1).